# Correct way to get model data inside of model callback

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Inside an afterSave, what is the best way to get information about `$this`.

For example. If I `debug($this->read())`, I get everything I need to know about the current record I am working with (associated models, etc..).

```
array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'id' => '12',
        'user_id' => '38'
        'body' => 'test',
        'created' => '2013-04-11 18:56:26',
        'modified' => '2013-04-11 18:56:26'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '38',
        'username' => 'example',
        'created' => '2013-01-26 18:25:39',
        'modified' => '2013-01-26 18:25:39',
        'first_name' => '',
        'last_name' => ''
    )
)
```

But doesn't that mean I am querying the db again? Shouldn't `$this` already have all this information in it?

What is the proper way to get the results of `$this->read()`, or this is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the proper way (`$this->read`), *depending* of what info you want about the record you just saved.
For example, if you're doing an insert, and your $data (used like `Comment->save($data)`) is:

```
array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'id' => '12',
        'user_id' => '38'
        'body' => 'test',
        'created' => '2013-04-11 18:56:26',
        'modified' => '2013-04-11 18:56:26'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '38',
        'username' => 'example',
        'created' => '2013-01-26 18:25:39',
        'modified' => '2013-01-26 18:25:39',
        'first_name' => '',
        'last_name' => ''
    )
)
```

and I mean *exactly* like that, then `$this->data` will still have that same info you just saved. `$this->data` is set to false only after `afterSave`.

However, if you do something like

```
$this->Comment->saveField('body', 'othertest');
```

the `$this->data` array in the afterSave will only contain something like

```
Array
(
    [id] => 6
    [body] => 'othertest'
    [modified] => 2013-04-11 15:17:45
)
```

In other words, if you want to get *all* the information related to a model regardless of the data passed as parameter in save(), you'll have to do a $this->read() (or find()).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the data like so:

```
public function afterSave($var = null){
    parent::afterSave($var);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->data);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
}
```

Try that code and see look through the output. This will give you access to the data that was posted, which should match the record if the save was a success. Also what version of CakePHP are you using and what are you attempting to do?

Read is fine though.